# Can you run Android Market from a virtual device?

Tags: android

Can you run the Android market app from a virtual device or in the emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The market is only allowed to run on devices that google licenced it to.

You could use a application backup tool to get the apk from your phone and then try to install this apk on an emulator. This violates the copyright from google that means copying the market apk is likely to be illegal, and it does not work because the market uses a shared library that is not present on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run it.

Comment: Would you elaborate, please? How do I run it?

Comment: You need to grab the market .apk from somewhere else (try your phone :)), as it doesn't come built into the emulator.

Comment: I don't have an Android phone. Where would you recommend I get it from? Thanks!

Comment: @Emanuil: The Android Market is only distributed on devices. It is not available for separate download, except from those violating copyright.

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me:

http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/11/how-to-install-android-market-in-google.html

EDIT: this could possibly be violating user licences.

Extra input required about licences

Answer (score 0):

Not with AVD. But you can install android on a pc (http://www.android-x86.org/download) using vmware, virtualbox, .... Then can log in with your Google account and install apps from Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com) for this purpose as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18546121/1922917). You'll be able to use it as a normal device, installing apps from the store under your Google account.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know which apps are avaible on Android Market you can use [AndroidPIT](http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/market/apps).