# What to do if unable to install IntelHAXM for Android Development?

Tags: android

Im unable to install IntelHAXM and as far as I know it would be of great help for using my Virtual Device when developing Android apps.
I cant install it because "this computer does not support intel visualisation technology haxm cannot be installed" - I get this error when I run the installer. On the official site it says that I need to have an Intel processor (which I do) and at least 1 GB of Ram (I have 2)

What can I do now, since I cant install this. Go out and get another computer and hope it will work?

Is there any alternative to using IntelHAXM?

Comment: You don't need HAXM.  Just use an ARM emulator.  Everything you need to know is on the Android developer site.

Comment: I watched some tutorials where they said this will dramatically speed up my emulator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) is a hardware-assisted virtualization engine (hypervisor) that uses Intel Virtualization Technology (Intel® VT)

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

this is why you can't install it.

well you have 3 alternatives:

- develop with the slow emulator
- get a processor or pc that supports IntelHAXM
- Get an Android device ([here is a link how you can use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116724/how-to-use-android-phone-instead-of-emulator))

Comment: getting an android device in two days :)

Comment: great! i my opinion that's the bestway to develop an android app

Comment: that was going to be my next question :D

Answer (score 3):

There's an alternative to the 3 options that Philipp mentioned.

[Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/). The project started with `AndroVM`, fundamentally a VM running Android and then evolved to where it is now.

It offers some **advantages** over the emulator: speed, ability to access the Play Store and install apps through it, controls for simulating GPS, hardware acceleration with OpenGL, etc. It's under development but the feedback seems to be very good.

The main **disadvantage** for now is that it offers limited system images: 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3 (in preview).

**Update May 2014:**
Google Apps is no longed included officially, but it can be installed manually (look in XDA-Developers forums).
The main disadvantage it had is gone since there's plenty of system images available now (all the latest 4.1-4.4 plus Gingerbread).

Comment: I love Genymotion (I use it daily), but it should be mentioned that, like HAXM, it requires a compatible processor in order to use hardware acceleration.

Comment: Since Genymotion uses VirtualBox underneath, VB can make use of the VT-x functionality if available for your processor. As always, virtual machine performance is very dependant on your processor. HAXM has gotten better and makes the Android emulator much more usable. What makes Genymotion better, for me at least, is the capability to install apps from the Play Store and the controls for the different sensors. For instance, suppose you are developing an app using the YouTube Android Player API, you are required to have the YouTube app installed. You can't test your app in the emulator.

Comment: I agree with everything you said :) However, the OP specifically states that he has a Intel processor which does NOT support hardware virtualization, so I thought it best to mention that it **might** not work in Genymotion/VirtualBox either - even though as you mention, it does provide better support for HW virtualization than HAXM.

Comment: Agreed. It's not magic especially when lacking VT-x, worth trying how it performs on a non VT-x processor though.